# GDataDB with OAuth 2.0?

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api, google-sheets-api, gdatadb

I was working on an C# Windows Form Application (.NET 4.5) that I had left for a while, and when I came back to it and tried to log in to get data from a google spreadsheet I got an error saying "execution of authentication request returned unexpected result 404".

From what I've been able to tell, I need to change to OAuth 2.0 in the application, but I'm not quite sure how to do that, using [GDataDB](https://github.com/mausch/GDataDB).

This is the code that uses GDataDB and tries to access the spreadsheet.

```
    DatabaseClient client = new DatabaseClient(EmailBox.Text, PasswordBox.Text);

    const string dbName = "SpreadsheetName";
    // Error gets thrown here in client.GetDatabase
    IDatabase database = client.GetDatabase(dbName);
```

Comment: You really need to provide something to work with. Your question is like "Hey doctor, I have a very strong headache. Am I gonna die?" kind of thing.

Comment: As you said, for this error, you should move to oauth 2.0 for your application. check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize and https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5101